# Passing secrets as output between jobs in a Github workflow

Tags: bash, github, jwt, github-actions

I am trying to pass a JWT token in between jobs but something prevents it to be passed correctly. According to the docs, if I want to pass variables between jobs I need to use `outputs` as explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs:%7E:text=in%2Dprogress%3A%20true-,jobs.%3Cjob_id%3E.outputs,-You%20can%20use). What I am doing is the following:

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  get-service-url:
    ...does something not interesting to us...
  get-auth-token:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      API_TOKEN: ${{ steps.getauthtoken.outputs.API_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Get Token
        id: getauthtoken
        run: |
          API_TOKEN:<there is a full JWT token here>
          echo -n "API_TOKEN=$API_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  use-token:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [get-service-url,get-auth-token]
    name: Run Tests
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          newman run ${{ github.workspace }}/tests/collections/my_collection.json --env-var "service_url=${{needs.get-service-url.outputs.service_URL}}" --env-var "auth_token=${{needs.get-auth-token.outputs.API_TOKEN}}"
```

So, during a run, in my output I see:

```
Run newman run /home/runner/work/my-repo/my-repo/tests/collections/my_collection.json  --env-var "service_url=https://test.net" --env-var "auth_token="
```

At first I thought there was something wrong in passing the token itself between jobs. Hence I tried
to put a dummy token an export it in the output. In my `get-auth-token` job, the call to output it became:

```
echo -n "API_TOKEN=test" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

and in the log I saw it there:

```
--env-var "auth_token=test"
```

so the way I am passing it intra jobs is fine. Moreover, the token is there and is correct because I hard coded one to simplify my tests. Indeed if in my `get-auth-token` job I try to `echo $API_TOKEN` I see in the logs `***` which makes me understand Github is correctly obfuscating it.
I then tried not to pass it in between jobs. So I created the same token, hardcoded, right before the `newman run` command and referenced it in the `newman run` directly and tada! The log now is:

```
Run newman run /home/runner/work/my-repo/my-repo/tests/collections/my_collection.json  --env-var "service_url=https://test.net" --env-var "auth_token=***"
```

So the token is there! But I need it to be coming from another job. There is something preventing the token to be passed in between jobs and I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: According to [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs), "**Outputs containing secrets are redacted on the runner and not sent to GitHub Actions.**".

Comment: missed that line.. thank you.. is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: How is `API_TOKEN` being generated? In that very step? Or, is it part of the secrets?

Comment: `API_TOKEN` is generated through a CLI that I install in that job, that's why it's a separate job and would like to keep it as such. I need to install different dependencies, an internal CLI and thank to this CLI I am able to retrieve a JWT token. In order to keep things separated I tried to isolate such job instead of having everything together in 1 job only. Plus this is something that can happen concurrently with other jobs at the beginning of my CI pipeline.. this is another reason for having it a separate job.

Comment: Right. Can you not make it some repo level variable and use that directly?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the logic of the repo unfortunately cause the CLI we internally use to get this token is a separate product.. I am reading a way to encrypt the secret and pass that in between jobs and maybe Github allows it.. giving it a try now if there is no other solution

Comment: Actually, by "repo level variable", I meant to have a common place accessible to all the jobs to access this generated token. You can use the workflow level [variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables) for it. As the jobs are run in different runners and storing a file wouldn't be feasible, having a global place for such values makes more sense. BTW, looks like `jobs.<job_id>` is missing in your workflow. Maybe, you deliberately removed it for conciseness.

Comment: we were talking about in another stackoverflow thread where you were trying to help me with this issue:) I still didn't manage workflow variables work and share variables between independent jobs! Could you show me a solution on how to export a variable in one job, into a workflow variable, and reuse it in another job maybe?

Comment: ah and yes I missed `jobs.<job_id>` cause I forgot it sorry but it's there! Question updated @Azeem

Comment: It would be similar to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow. I'll try to write a small example later.

Comment: Are you saying that the `env:  First_Name: Mona` at the end of the code snippet is the right way to export a variable and make it visible on workflow level?

Comment: Nope. That's the step level. I'm referring to `env: DAY_OF_WEEK: Monday` which is at the workflow level.

Comment: okey, but then since one of my jobs is the one responsible to get the JWT token, how do I export that value back into a workflow level variable from within the job?

Comment: I revisited your scenario and you're already getting the output but it's encrypted and not being sent to the next job. Only that part needs to be figured out. Have you figured that out yet?

Comment: didn't you say that if we manage to export it into an environment variable under `env` it will be visible? Otherwise no, unfortunately didn't figure out yet how to pass it in between jobs by using `output`

Comment: Yes, I did. But, in your case, everything is dynamic. The token generation is dynamic so exporting to `env` at the workflow level is not possible because it's not dynamically changed. The other option that was ruled out was to use a file but as these are different jobs and are run on different runners, that's not possible either i.e. retention via files. If you go a level higher, then there are cache and artifacts. With cache, you could save and restore. With artifacts, you could upload and download. With cache/artifacts, you would always remove these using the `if: always()` condition.

Comment: Figured it out finally, will post an answer here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out a trick to make this happen. Consists on temporarily "obfuscating" the secret to the eyes of Github.

In the job where I retrieve the secret I encode it and export it to `GITHUB_OUTPUT`:

```
API_TOKEN_BASE64=`echo -n <my_secret> | base64 -w 0`
echo -n "API_TOKEN=$API_TOKEN_BASE64" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

In the job where I need the secret I decode it (and use where needed):

```
API_TOKEN=`echo -n ${{needs.get-auth-token.outputs.API_TOKEN}} | base64 --decode`
```

Comment: That's great! Question: Was your generated API token in cleartext, or some other form before Base64?

Comment: @Azeem clear text!:)

Comment: there are two problems with using only base64:
- this may not work, if there is a short secret that is likely to occur randomly in base64 form - GHA will recognize this by mistake - I've seen it first hand
- this is not very secure, it just bypasses a security feature

Comment: Watch out: This will print your encoded secret in the logs, which can be decoded by ANYONE!!

Answer (score 2):

To make sure we don't leak secrets, one can use encryption.

The easiest way I've found and used successfully is using `gpg` and `base64`:

1. Create a GPG passphrase and set as a secret named `PASSPHRASE` (make sure it is strong).
2. Create outputs that are encrypted and encoded (please ignore the old outputs syntax), e.g.:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Docker image
    ...
    outputs:
      IMAGE_PATH: ${{ steps.out.outputs.IMAGE_PATH }}
    steps:
      - name: Process env vars
        run: |
          echo "IMAGE_PATH=/tmp/my-image.tar" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: Create outputs
        id: out
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=IMAGE_PATH::$(echo -n '${{ env.IMAGE_PATH }}' | gpg --symmetric --quiet --batch --passphrase ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }} --output - | base64 -w0)"
```

3. Read, decode and decrypt the outputs, e.g.:

```
  release-to-dev:
    needs: build
    ...
    steps:
      - name: Process outputs
        run: |
          echo "IMAGE_PATH=$(echo -n '${{ needs.build.outputs.IMAGE_PATH }}' | base64 -d | gpg --decrypt --quiet --batch --passphrase ${NOT_A_PASSPHRASE} --output -)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

The original `IMAGE_PATH` value will be now available in the other job as plaintext in env vars as `${IMAGE_PATH}` or `${{ env.IMAGE_PATH }}`.