# How to access needs.job-id.outputs in the container image credentials fields?

Tags: github-actions, cicd, hashicorp-vault

I have this workflow

```yaml
name: my-workflow

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["_.//"]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:  
  set-var:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    name: set-var
    steps:
      - name: Import Secrets
        id: import-secrets
        uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v2.7.4
        with:
          url: https://vault-enterprise.my-company.com
          method: approle
          path: approle-busapp
          roleId: ${{ vars.VAULT_ROLEID }}
          secretID: ${{ secrets.VAULT_SECRET_ID }}
          namespace: abc/efg
          secrets: |
            DEV/data/SECRETS a | A ;
            DEV/data/SECRETS b | B ;
            DEV/data/SECRETS c | C ;

      - id: set-var
        run: |
          A="${{ env.A }}"
          B="${{ env.B }}"
          C="${{ env.C }}"

          echo "A=$A" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "B=$B" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "C=$C" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    outputs:
      A: ${{ steps.set-var.outputs.A }}
      B: ${{ steps.set-var.outputs.B }}
      C: ${{ steps.set-var.outputs.C }}

  job-1:
    needs: [set-var]
    name: job-1
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    container:
      image: company-artifactory/my-actions-runner-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.A }}
        password: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.B }}
    env:
      C: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.C }}
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          echo $C
  job-2:
    needs: [set-var]
    name: job-2
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    container:
      image: company-artifactory/my-actions-runner-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.A }}
        password: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.B }}
    env:
      C: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.C }}
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          echo $C
```

As you see I am using a custom image name **company-artifactory/my-actions-runner-image:latest** as the runner image to run job-1 and job-2 in a container and it needs credentials to pull the image.

I am trying to us `needs.set-var.outputs.A` and `needs.set-var.outputs.B` to pull the secret form vault but it seems like GitHub Actions do not support this. I don't have access to needs.outputs in the container.credentials.

How can I make it work?

Another concern that I have is sharing secrets between jobs. How do I do this securely?  Because right now I am seeing a warning that the secret shared as output is not secure.

### **UPDATE**

I am adding a new version of the question here to clarify one part of the question.

```
name: my-workflow

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["_.//"]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:  
  job-0:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    name: job-0
    steps:
      - name: Import Secrets
        id: import-secrets
        uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v2.7.4
        with:
          url: https://vault-enterprise.my-company.com
          method: approle
          path: approle-busapp
          roleId: ${{ vars.VAULT_ROLEID }}
          secretID: ${{ secrets.VAULT_SECRET_ID }}
          namespace: abc/efg
          secrets: |
            DEV/data/SECRETS a | A ;
      - id: print-secret
        run: |
          echo $A
          echo "${{ env.A }}"
      - id: set-env
        run: |
          AAA="${{ env.A }}"
          echo "AAA=$AAA" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - id: test-set-env-step
        run: |
          echo "this is a test"
          echo ${{ steps.set-env.outputs.AAA }}
    outputs:
      AAA: ${{ steps.set-env.outputs.AAA }}

  job-1:
    needs: [job-0]
    name: job-1
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    container:
      image: company-artifactory/my-actions-runner-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.A }}
        password: ${{ needs.set-var.outputs.B }}
    env:
      B: ${{ needs.job-0.outputs.AAA }}
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          echo $A
          echo $AA
          echo $AAA
          echo $B
          echo ${{env.B}}
          echo ${{env.A}}
          echo ${{env.AA}}
          echo ${{env.AAA}}
```

- in job-0 in the step "print-secret" the value of "a" from Vault is **successfully printed twice**.
- in job-0 the "test-set-env-step" is **not printing** the value of a.
- in job-1 the value of "a" from Vault is **not printed at all**.

and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285937/11065874) question, I then did this

```
.
.
.
      - id: set-env
        run: |
          AAA=${{ env.A }}
          AAA=`echo -n $AAA | base64 -w 0`
          echo "AAA=$AAA" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    outputs:
      AAA: ${{ steps.set-env.outputs.AAA }}
.
.
.
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          C=`echo -n ${{needs.job-0.outputs.AAA}} | base64 --decode`
.
.
.
```

but nothing got printed in the second job

Comment: What is the error that you get with the `needs` context? According to the [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), the `needs` seems to be supported. Also, you don't have to set the retrieved secrets separately to output parameters, they are [already available as env vars and output params](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-action?tab=readme-ov-file#example-usage). That means the step `set-var` in your workflow is redundant.

Comment: @Azeem can you please see the updated question? I added a new experiment to clarify

Comment: In `job-0`, print `steps.set-env.outputs.AAA` in a new step to verify whether it's being set or not.

Comment: @Azeem No it did not. updated the question with the new piece of information

Comment: Can you please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a repo for this? Seems like everything is fine. Only issue that I see is `needs.set-var.outputs.A` whereas it should be `needs.job-0.outputs.A` for `username` and `password`.

Comment: what I created is an MVCE. the problem is that we dont have a github action runtime so that you can copy my example right into your terminal. or maybe there exist such a lab env and I am not aware of

Comment: 'in job-0 the "test-set-env-step" is not printing the value of a' -- that would be a concern, there's no reason that shouldn't be working, and, changing your self hosted runner to `ubuntu-latest` and replacing the `uses: hashicorp/vault-action` with `echo  "A=some_value" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`, it does work. But if you're successfully printing it in `print-secret` there's no reason it should vanish before `test-set-env-step`. Tested with and without trailing newline.